# Django AdminModel inline causes apache to run at 100% CPU

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have these models in my django app:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    pass
class Link(models.Model):
    start = models.ForeignKey(Stop)
    runtime = models.TimeField()
    position = models.IntegerField()
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
```

and these admin models:

```
class LinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Link
class RouteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'show_link_count')
    inlines = [
        LinkInline,
    ]

    def queryset(self, request):
        return Route.objects.annotate(link_count=Count('link'))

    def show_link_count(self, inst):
        return inst.link_count
    show_link_count.short_description = "Stop count"
```

When I try looking at any specific Route (and see a list of Links associated with it) it causes the apache server to run 100% on one thread and steadily allocate more and more memory.

Am I doing something wrong here?

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 with django 1.6 and apache 2.4.6

Comment: How many records are in your `Stop` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a lot of records in the `Stop` model. A solution is to `raw_id_fields` to link inline. Try this:

```
class LinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Link
    raw_id_fields = ('start',)
```

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the problem. It was fetching over 400 000 of records from the database to display in the select input field. Not a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

As Bogdan said, you problem is probably caused by tons of record of `Stop`. Instead the way of using `raw_id_fields`, you may still want to explicitly view all your `Stop` instance in your `Link` inline. This can be achieved, but it is complicated.

Change your Inline class to

```
class LinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Link
    form = LinkForm
```

Then create Linkform

```
Class LinkForm(forms.Form):
    start = Stop.objects.values_list('id', 'something')
    #I don't believe you just have an empty class

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LinkForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['start'] = Stop.objects.get(id=cleaned_data['start'])
        return cleaned_data
```

In this case, you will still load all the instances you have for you `Stop` model, but also give you a quick loading speed.

The code may be confused, let me know if you need more explanation on this.